# SignalR, not getting data from server in client

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, signalr

In IE all serverside send method aint delivering data to the client function. I works in all other browsers.

The method is hit, but no data in the response.

(SignalR logging) SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'ping' on hub 'chat'.

Serverside C#/Signalr:

```
public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        var info = "ORC";
        Clients.Caller.ping("OnReconnected", info);
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
```

Clientside Angular:

```
chat.client.ping = onPing;
function onPing(note, info) {
    if (info == 'OCO') {
        foo();
    }
    console.log(note)
}
```

I have disabled ajax cache: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

Stil no data is send back to the client.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like a problem with delivery times from server to client. I get back, when I have a solution to this.

Comment: The problem was in Task Sync, and know I got it to work in all browsers. Exept in Safari 5.14 for Windows.